# Regex change in keyup handler to allow alphabets in specific location

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am using following validation to put autodash in my textbox .

```
   $('input#txtReportingNum').keyup(function (e) {
                       this.value = this.value
                        .match(/\d*/g).join('')
                        .match(/(\d{0,2})(\d{0,2})(\d{0,4})/).slice(1).join('-')
                        .replace(/-*$/g, '');
               });

  Input = string_1-String_2-String_3
```

The above code does not allow me to enter alphabets . How can i change the above pattern to make String_2 and String_3 to allow both alphabets and numbers. Can anybody please help me to get this done ?

I want to make something like 89-e3-w323

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this
    `$('input#txtReportingNum').keyup(function (e) {
        this.value = this.value
        .match(/[a-fA-F0-9]*/g).join('')
        .match(/(\d{0,2})([0-9][a-fA-F])(\d{0,4})/).slice(1).join('-')
        .replace(/-*$/g, '');
    });
    Input = string_1-String_2-String_3`

Comment: The above allows alphabets for String_1 also  . can you please correct it ?

Comment: sure. I edited it the answer. Let me know if it does what you want it to.

Comment: Autodash failing once we select letter first . Dash shall occur accordingly.

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted to happen, that first string can only be numbers?

Comment: dash should come after we enter something like 89 then 89- then it should allow 2 either number or alphabets and so on

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what isn't happening that you are expecting to happen. Can you explain?

Comment: In javascript, I have tested it and it seems to work fine. I have done var a = "89e3w323";

var b = a.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9]*/g).join('')
        .match(/(\d{0,2})([a-zA-Z0-9]{0,2})([a-zA-Z0-9]{0,4})/).slice(1).join('-')
        .replace(/-*$/g, '');

b was equal to
"89-e3-w323"

Comment: Sorry . i was bit confused with my own requirement . Whatever u posted is correct only . I just need one more help . In string_2 only for 2nd letter i want alphabets (Only from A to F) . Please update . Something like 89-1A-0342

Comment: Only capital letters from A to F or also those in lowercase? How about String3, should they only be number as before or string3 is good as is?

Comment: both lowercase and uppercase

Comment: ok. I updated the answer. Let me know if it works as expected.